# Apache2.4.7 homepage-logo (13)Permission denied

Tags: permissions, apache2

i created a svg for my homepage(logo).

I placed it in

`/var/www/html/mm/pictures`

The html is correct(syntax and path to the image) but it is only displaying alt text.

A quick look into `/var/log/apache2/error.log` gives following output:

```
[Sun Apr 05 15:14:54.570044 2015] [core:error] [pid 2114] (13)Permission denied: [client 84...] AH00132: file permissions deny server access: /var/www/html/mm/pictures/logo.svg, referer: http://84../
```

**Permissions from logo.svg down to /var/www/html/mm :**

logo.svg:

```
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
```

/var/www/html/mm/pictures:

```
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
```

/var/www/html/mm:

```
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
```

So, for me it looks just fine, world read access is granted so why is access for www-data denied?

**Maybe something important to know:**

logo.svg was created on my laptop(not the server) with Inkscape and transmitted over openvpn and ssh using securecopy `scp` to the home-directory pof my server and then from my server to `/var/www/html/mm/pictures`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need change owner of /var/www/html/mm?

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/mm
```

Comment: Thank you but that is not logical. It's world readable and the HTML CSS files are displayed correctly. I think it could be a config issue because it is only at pictures or the image is encrypted??

Comment: check if image with other extension (.png or .jpg) work correctly? maybe apache block .svg files?

Comment: No PNG is also not working. It is not the extension, it is the accessibility of the www-data user which is denied

Comment: Maybe problem in vhosts? Do you show your config?

Comment: No please guide me what i need look up

Comment: ok, if /var/www/html/mm/ is document root, please create file with name 1.svg and check if you have access to 1.svg: http://yoursite/1.svg. If not - create 1.html with some text, and check if http://yoursite/1.html is work correctly. After this copy 1.html to /var/www/html/mm/pictures and check if http://yoursite/pictures/1.html is work correctly. Waiting for result

Comment: I created 1.svg with root in /var/www/html/mm and do have access with mysite/1.svg! Also i can access mysite/pictures/ but not the file in it called logo.svg :`You don't have permission to access /pictures/logo.png on this server.`